# Would you like to tell me the reason why the version of bundler remains "2.2.16" in Gemfile.lock, even though I updated bundler to "2.2.21"?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My ruby ​​version is 2.6.6, my mysql version is 8.0.23, my mysql2 version is 0.5.3, my bundler version is 2.2.21, my rails version is 5.0.7.2, and my Xcode version is 12.5.

I use macOS Big Sur(version 11.4) and the text editor "Atom".

The bundler (version 2.2.16) should have been updated
to "2.2.21 " as bellow.

```
$ bundler -v

Your /Users/****/.bundle/config config includes `BUNDLE_--LOCAK`, 
which contains the dash character (`-`).
This is deprecated, because configuration through `ENV` should be possible, 
but `ENV` keys cannot include dashes.
Please edit /Users/****/.bundle/config and replace any dashes in configuration keys with a triple underscore (`___`).
Bundler version 2.2.21
```

But the version of bundler remains "2.2.16" in the following
file "Gemfile.lock".

```
BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.16
```

Please tell me the reason why the version of bundler remains "2.2.16" in Gemfile.lock.

Answer (score 2):

Your existing application will continue to use the bundler version it was created with, unless you explicitly update it.

To update your application bundler, run this command:

```
bundle update --bundler
```

Alternatively:

```
bundle <VERSION> update --bundler
```

Comment: Thank you so well for answering my question!